# Xampp control panel mysql won't start

Tags: mysql, xampp

Hello I downloaded the exp english version of Xampp.
When I go into my XAMPP control panel I can start Apache Filezilla and murcery but I cant start mysql when I click start it says stop for about 3 seconds and then stops and it won't stay running.
When I try and go into phpmyadmin it then says :

Error
SQL query:

```
SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8';
```

MySQL said:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax near ''utf8';' at line 1 

Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
```

Can anyone help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the logs for MySQL. There is likely a problem with the configuration and it is pretty good about saying what went wrong.

You can also verify that you do not have anything running on the MySQL port you have configured with XAMPP. Already having another service running is a frequent issue on startup of a service.

Comment: Thanks but I already did and only mysql port3306 came up system on

Comment: I had to start it from xampp/mysql_start.bat and it worked

Answer (score 2):

Most often, there may be another MySQL installation (and service)(that was installed in a different directory) running. The two MySQL services are competing with each other to access the same port.

Try uninstalling the alternate MySQL version and then XAMPP's MySQL instance should start running alomost by itself with no further actions.

Comment: where would i look for this?